# Alternative to Autokey (text expander program)

Tags: alternative, productivity, autokey

for more than a year I have been looking for simple and stable text expander application on Ubuntu. There is Autokey, but it doesn't work for many people (there are a few threads here about this). For me (Ubuntu 13.10) it crashes all the time and skippes some characters,...

Is there any alternative (all I need is to automatically replace abbreviation that I type)?

I know there are extensions to browsers but that isn't solution.

It would be great it this would be preinstalled feature of Ubuntu :-)

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions!

Best regards
Jan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to AutoKey?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/547500/is-there-an-alternative-to-autokey)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Actionaz** ([homepage](http://wiki.actionaz.org/doku.php?id=en%3astart))

It is in the repository.

Comment: Thank you but I tried this software and I couldn't make it work as text expander - I always had to start a script manually :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you. Autokey wasn't working well and I didn't just want to use a browser plugin because I wanted to be able to use text expansion in other apps too, not just browsers. So I wrote this little script that prompts you for an abbreviation (snippet name) then pasts the fill text from your snippet file into the app your working in. You can check it out here - [Text Expander for Linux](http://leehblue.com/ubuntu-text-expander/)

Answer (score -1):

I finally gave up on autokey and switched to this solution

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2014/162/Workspace-Text-Expander

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.