# Is there an alternative to AutoKey?

Tags: software-recommendation, thunderbird, autokey

This questions was already asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446794/alternative-to-autokey-text-expander-program) 7 months, but had no correct answer. So I would like to ask again: Is there an alternative to AutoKey, which executes text expansions, when specific abbreviations are typed? 
My problem is that AutoKey skips randomly letters when I use this function in Thunderbird, while it always works fine in a text editor. This problem occurs since Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Autokey (text expander program)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446794/alternative-to-autokey-text-expander-program)

Comment: @Volodya The question there wasn't answered correctly in 7 months, as I have mentioned it :-)

Comment: But it doesn't make it not a duplicate. That question isn't closed, and if somebody wants to answer, they should do it there.

Comment: The issue with Thunderbird was fixed in Autokey 0.96.0
https://github.com/autokey/autokey/releases/

Answer (score 7):

Snippy seems to work for me quite nicely. No GUI, but quite functional. Glad I finally found a replacement.

http://leon.vankammen.eu/tech/snippy-autocompletion-for-console-and-browser-window-manager-using-bash.html

The link also mentions another choice in the comments.

Snippy itself is available via a tinyurl and installation is as follows:

```
curl -L "http://tinyurl.com/o9d6ch5" > snippy.sh 
chmod 755 snippy.sh
./snippy.sh
```

Alternatively, there appears to be an enhanced version located [here in github](https://gist.github.com/coderofsalvation/46549e3788ade2f3a938)

Installation works the same.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 0):

Snippy actually proved to be a very good idea, now I have a menu of scripts on the desktop.

A restructuring proved necessary, though, as xdotool doesn't work so well these days with window names ( and I tried every possible solution -my OS is Ubuntu 22.04 w/XFCE ).

I kept only dmenu:

```
#!/bin/bash
# snippy re-engineered

DIR=${HOME}/.snippy
APPS="dmenu"
DMENU_ARGS="-b"
TERMINAL=tilix # change to your favorite

init(){
  for APP in $APPS; do 
    which $APP >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
      read -p "install the following required utils? : $APPS (y/n)" reply
      if [ "$reply" == "y" ]; then
       sudo apt install --assume-yes ${APPS}; 
      fi
    }
  done
  if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo -e "created $DIR\n";
    mkdir "$DIR"; 
    printf 'hi it is $(date)' > "$DIR""/test";
  fi
  return 0
}

run(){
  # Use the filenames in the snippy directory as menu entries.
  cd ${DIR} 
  # Get the menu selection from the user.
  FILE=`find -L .  -type f | grep -v '^\.$' | sed 's!\.\/!!' | sort | /usr/bin/dmenu ${DMENU_ARGS}`
  
  # open terminal and execute
  if [ -z "$FILE" ]; then
      exit
  else
      ${TERMINAL} --title=$FILE --command="$SHELL $DIR/$FILE"
  fi

}

init && run
```

This update comes after many years, but it's proved helpful.